# Setting a website to fullscreen on all mobile devices

Tags: mobile, web, fullscreen, viewport

I'm trying to find a way to set the size of the body element of a website to the size of the available screen. On a desktop browser, it's easy: `width=height=100%` but on a mobile device it's not so simple:

Many device default to some initial zoom-setting that tries to display pages at an optimally readable scale. For Android, I can turn this off with the following `<head>`-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=high-dpi, initial-scale=1.0>
```

Now, setting the width of the body works as expected (under Android). The height is a whole different problem, since the browser will then set what 100% means based on the current location of the address bar. So, if your page was initially longer than visible and had been scrolled such that the address bar is off-screen, setting height to 100% has the desired effect. But as soon as the user moves the page down to expose the address bar, the height gets updated so that it is no longer possible to scroll back in the other direction.

So, for mobile devices, it seems that the only way to set the body height correctly is by setting it to a pixel size rather than 100%. But reading [this article on all the different available size measures (screen.height, window.outerheight, ...)](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/) gives me the shivers about making it work across devices:

Thus my question:

Is there a reliable, best-practice way to achieve setting the size of the body element on mobile devices such that the page takes up all available screen real-estate (including pushing the address bar off-screen), but no more? For extra credit: Can this be done, such that the user can still zoom in (but not out) on the page?

Solutions either using JavaScript or CSS or both are perfectly acceptable for me, but they should work across as many devices as possible, at the least on the desktop (IE6+, Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and on mobile devices (phones, tablets, Android, iOS, Windows Mobile).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely clear where you are heading with this, but see if any of these suggestions help.

For the meta tag, try

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0">
```

I'm not sure if target-densitydpi=high-dpi is required. Easy enough to replace if necessary though.

For the CSS

```
 html,
 body {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

And to hide the address bar, I've used [this code with good results](http://davidwalsh.name/hide-address-bar) before, or [here's another that I haven't used](http://menacingcloud.com/?c=iPhoneAddressBar)

Good luck!